# PySide6 QLabel padding not applied when unpolish, polished

Tags: python, pyside

I define style sheet and test.py like below.

I expected the label's text padding change 10px -> 100px but its not applied.
The background color changed to RED.
I test color, font-size as well, but only 'padding' didn't applied after click the button.

Can anyone explain why only padding not applied in style sheet?

**style**

```
.QLabel[text="OK"]{
  background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
    color: rgb(255,250,250);
    font-size: 24pt;
    padding: 10px;
}

.QLabel[text="ERR"]{
  background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    color: rgb(255,250,250);
    font-size: 24pt;
    padding: 100px;
}
```

**test.py**

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def set_style(self):
        with open('./style', 'r') as f:
            self.setStyleSheet(f.read())

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.set_style()
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('OK', self)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button', self)

        vlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vlayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        vlayout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.btn_clicked)

        self.show()

    def btn_clicked(self, a):
        self.label.setText("ERR")
        self.label.style().unpolish(self.label)
        self.label.style().polish(self.label)
        self.update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    win = MyWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: before btn click]
[image: after btn click]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

Just call `self.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())` to ensure that the style is actually reapplied.

### Explanation

While in some parts of the documentation (and some QSS related questions) there are references to `polish()` and `unpolish()`, those functions are not always guaranteed to "do everything".

The documentation partially explains what [`polish()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#polish) does:

> Initializes the *appearance* of the given widget.
> [...]
> Note that the default implementation does nothing. Reasonable actions in this function might be to call the QWidget::setBackgroundMode() function for the widget. Do not use the function to set, for example, the geometry.

In fact, what those two functions (which are *virtual*<sup>[1]</sup>) do is to, possibly, set something and restore it back, or the other way around. But that might not be sufficient. They could even do *nothing at all*.

Without going too deep into the implementation, suffices to say that [un]polishing is usually insufficient for the [box model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model) updates that are not directly related to the contents (like the font), and this is especially important for *property selectors*, as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types):

> Warning: If the value of the Qt property changes after the style sheet has been set, it might be necessary to force a style sheet recomputation. One way to achieve this is to unset the style sheet and set it again.

So, the easiest solution is just that: re-set the stylesheet.

In this case, the following will be enough:

```py
    def btn_clicked(self, a):
        self.label.setText("ERR")
        self.setStyleSheet(self.styleSheet())
```

Notes:

- calling `setStyleSheet()` with the current stylesheet *is* acceptable, as it's always guaranteed that the style will be computed again as long as the widget *already* uses a stylesheet, even indirectly; due to the *cascading* nature of QSS (as for CSS), this obviously *possibly* affects any child widget;
- calling `self.update()` (on the parent) is normally useless, as it will only schedule a *repaint* on that parent, so:

  - a scheduled repaint only calls `paintEvent()` again, and will normally have no effect on "changed" stylesheet, and that's because a paint function only cares about *painting* and should ***never*** call for geometry changes;
  - the repaint usually happens only on the widget for which it was scheduled: in most cases, children widgets will completely ignore it (so they will not be repainted);
- as a general rule, it's usually suggested to avoid to use QSS property selectors for properties that might change at runtime; while, as explained above and in the documentation, this *can* be worked around, it's still unsafe and usually discouraged; always use this feature with care and after deep consideration of the possible alternatives;

<sup>[1] With C++, "virtuals" are functions that can be overridden by a subclass and that can be called *internally* by Qt; this results in various aspects: 1. non-virtual functions can only be explicitly called from PyQt/PySide, so you could theoretically use any name you want, as it won't affect the default behavior; 2. some non-virtual functions are explicitly called by PyQt when using the `uic` module, so it's *partially* safe to override them for the reason above; 3. abstract classes might require virtuals to be overridden in order to be used (i.e., the `data()` method of QAbstractItemModel); 4. the base implementation might do nothing, and the virtual is provided for convenience (the `tabInserted()` of QTabBar); 5. the base implementation might *do something*, and you may need to reimplement "that something" or at least call the base implementation (the mouse/key events of QWidget);</sup>

Comment: I'd like to use setStyleSheet but worrying program performance. Since I have to detect OK/ERR every 40msec.

Comment: @HyunYoungGo Then, since the update frequency is that high, three things: 1. don't use stylesheets; 2. don't change a property that could affect geometry that often (it doesn't really matter if the *actual* change could happen less often); 3. explain such important matters in the question. Sorry, but, with all due respect, I *did* answer what was being asked: your requisite is quite important, as it potentially affects performance, and your question has absolutely **no** mention about it.